# Automation Error trying to GET API data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, api

I'm trying to create a sheet to show the current weather at certain locations. I'm completely new to APIs and have looked at several online tutorials. Still feel like a beginner.

I've tried to get some data just to test if it works but the code shows an error at the `xml_obj.open` line. Automation Error (Error 440). The url to the API works just fine when I paste it into my web browser. Anyone knows what might be wrong?

```
Sub API_JSON()

Dim xml_obj As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Set xml_obj = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

xml_obj.Open "GET", "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=xxxxxxx", False 'cant get past this line

'xxxxxxx is my key to the API

xml_obj.send

MsgBox (xml_obj.responseText)


End Sub
```

Comment: A URL typically begins with http/https   Your browser might add that automatically, but XMLHTTP won't do that.

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem! :)